not able to use async thunks with dispatch
To make this concise, I will display only the minimal code of interest:
slice.ts:
export const fetchProjects = createAsyncThunk(
    'projects/fetchProjects',
    async () => {
        return prototypeItems;
    }
);

const projectsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'projects',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      // some normal reducers here that work fine with dispatch
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchProjects.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.projects = action.payload;
        });
    }
});

export default projectsSlice.reducer;

store.ts:
import reducer from "slice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
});

export type NotebooksDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export default store;

component.tsx:
// all needed imports...

export function Example() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch<NotebooksDispatch>();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProjects());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return <div></div>
}

Compilation error in the line dispatch(fetchProjects()): Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<ProjectItem[], void, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnknownAction'.
I've seen other Stack Overflow / GitHub issues, and many of them suggest I should define the type in useDispatch (which I tried to do using NotebooksDispatch).
The error should be in the definition of NotebooksDispatch, since when I change const dispatch = useDispatch<NotebooksDispatch>() to use <any>, the code works as intended (of course, this is just for testing, I would like the proper solution).

It is recommended to follow the Typescript Quick Start guide.
See specifically:

Define Root State and Dispatch Types

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
  },
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch



Define Typed Hooks

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>()




I was able to reproduce the error you described

and with the following update to create and export typed useDispatch and useSelector hooks for the app code to use it appears to be resolved.

store.ts
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import reducer from "./slice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type NotebooksDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<NotebooksDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>();

export default store;

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAppDispatch } from "./store";
import { fetchProjects } from "./slice";

export function Example() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProjects());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <div></div>
}


It works! I thought useDispatch.withTypes would be equivalent to useDispatch. Well, thanks for your help!

@GustavoL. It might have been the case in Redux-Toolkit v1.*, but I think v2 had some significant TS changes. Glad this was helpful. Cheers!
